# Laravel Nova loading time optimization

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I use Laravel Nova to manage an online shop selling courses. As so, my `App/Nova/Course` resource is very big and contains a lot of dependencies.

I am currently trying to associate a `Course` in a `Step` (when the user complete a `Step`, they win a badge), using a `MorphedByMany` field (a `Step` can contain either `Course` or `Quizz`).

```php
public function fields(Request $request)
{
    return [
        ID::make()->sortable(),

        Text::make('Label')
            ->required()
            ->sortable(),

        MorphedByMany::make('Courses')->fields(function () {
            return [
                Number::make('Awarded points', 'awarded_points')
                    ->sortable()
                    ->required(),
            ];
        }),
    ];
}
```

My problem is that the `Course` select in the Laravel Nova form take a long time to load due to `App/Nova/Course` complexity.

Is there a way to reduce this loading time?